# Как удалить файл из директории 'public' в Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, файлы

Всем привет!

Как мне удалить `img` файлы из директории `'/public/posts/'`?
В данной папке имеется несколько файлов:

```
-public
--posts
---1.jpg
---2.jpg
---3jpg
```

Файл модели:

Post.rb

```
before_destroy :remove_file
def remove_file
 getAllImages.each do |file|
  File.delete(Rails.root.join('public', file))
 end
end
```

Error:

```
Errno::ENOENT in PostsController#destroy

No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - /posts/1.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас коллекция getAllImages скорее всего содержит абсолютные пути к файлам /posts/1.jpg, которые метод join тоже считает абсолютными от рута, поэтому он не добавляет к ним префикс, а рассматривает как есть, попробуйте удалить первый символ, у file

```
before_destroy :remove_file
def remove_file
 getAllImages.each do |file|
  File.delete(Rails.root.join('public', file[1..-1]))
 end
end
```

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло!